$z , w \in \mathbb{C}:$ $ |z - 4 + 3i| = 1$, $|w - 4 + 3i| = 5$, and $|z - w| = \sqrt{31}$. $P = |5z + w| = ?$

$z , w \in \mathbb{C}: |z - 4 + 3i| = 1, |w - 4 + 3i| = 5,$ and $|z - w| = \sqrt{31}. P = |5z + w| = ?$

Hi, I was solving a problem and got to this point where I needed to find $P.$ I was thinking of a vector solution by letting $A$ and $B$ represent $z$ and $w$, respectively, on the complex plane and $I(4; -3)$ be the center of both circles that $z$ and $w$ moving on (with radius $1$ and $5,$ respectively).
Then $P = |5\vec{OA} + \vec{OB}| = |5\vec{OI} + 5\vec{IA} + \vec{IB}|$ while $|\vec{IA} - \vec{IB}| = \sqrt{31}$ and $IA = 1, IB = 5, OI = 5.$
Sparing up the first equation gets me: $P^2 = 25OI^2 + 25IA^2 + IB^2 + 10\vec{OI}(5\vec{IA} + \vec{IB})  + 10\vec{IA}.\vec{IB}$
Squaring the second equation will allow me to obtain $\vec{IA}.\vec{IB},$ but that was as far as I got. Please advise.
Thank you!

This answer is inspired by @idon'tknowwhatiamdoing 's approach of shifting the center.
Let $m = z - 4 + 3i$ and $n = w - 4 + 3i.$ Then $|m| = 1, |n| = 5,$ and $|m - n| = \sqrt{31}$
$P = |5z + w| = |5m + n + 6(4 - 3i)| \geq ||5m + n| - 30|$
Let $A$ and $B$ represent $m$ and $n,$ respectively, on the complex plane $Oxy.$
$|m - n|^2 = |\vec{OA} - \vec{OB}|^2 = OA^2 + OB^2 - 2\vec{OA}\vec{OB} = 31 \implies \vec{OA}\vec{OB} = -\frac52.$
$|5m + n|^2 = |5\vec{OA} + \vec{OB}|^2 = 25OA^2 + OB^2 + 10\vec{OA}.\vec{OB} = 25 \implies |5m + n| = 5$
$\implies P \geq 25.$
